# get saved value on input flatpickr angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, flatpickr

I have a flatpickr angular component that I use to save a date with Format:

```
<input ng-flatpickr class="flatpickr" fp-opts="$ctrl.dateOpts" fp-on-setup="$ctrl.dateDebutSetup(fpItem)" ng-model="$ctrl.selected.selectedDateDebut" data-enabletime="true" placeholder="Selectionner Date..">
```

When I save this date I have no error, I get the ng-model with the

```
$scope.dateDebutSetup = function (fpItem) {
    fpItem.set("onChange", function (selectedDates, dateStr, instance) {
        $scope.selected.selectedDateDebut = selectedDates[0];
    });
};
```

and I save it in my db

```
selection.selectedDateDebut= $filter('date')(new Date($scope.selected.selectedDateDebut), "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
```

But when I try to get the saved value on my input to modify it, It's doesn't work, the value is not loaded

I tried a lot of examples but I don't find a solution:

```
$ctrl.selected.selectedDatesDebut = $filter('date')(indispo.dateDebut, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
```

this one:

```
$ctrl.selected.selectedDatesFin = moment(indispo.dateFin).format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm');
```

or Juste with:

```
$ctrl.selected.selectedDatesFin = new Date (indispo.dateDebut);
```

Can someone help me please. And thank's in advance :)